# bazel tell external dependency maven to use local jar

Tags: bazel

GAPID uses bazel, and has external dependency that uses maven.  I get this error:

```
ERROR: C:/users/pemgithub/_bazel_pemgithub/3mdmxsrc/external/gapic_third_party/BUILD.bazel:19:1: no such package '@io_grpc_context//jar': Failed to fetch Maven dependency: Could not transfer artifact io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.16.1 from/to io_grpc_context (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): connect timed out and referenced by '@gapic_third_party//:grpc'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:pkg' failed; build aborted: no such package '@io_grpc_context//jar': Failed to fetch Maven dependency: Could not transfer artifact io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.16.1 from/to io_grpc_context (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): connect timed out
INFO: Elapsed time: 11.014s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
    Fetching @com_github_pkg_errors; Restarting. 10s
```

I think it's related to proxy (corporate network).  I tried adding proxy settings to C:/users/pemgithub/.m2/settings.html.  However, bazel maven does not seem to be using the proxy settings.

So I'd rather just download the jar files manually and tell bazel maven to use the local jar files.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Bazel currently (July 2019) does not support this properly. While `rules_jvm_external` is recommended as the successor to `maven_jar`, it does not read Maven's `~/.m2/settings.xml` and it also does not supporting using already downloaded artifacts from `~/.m2/repository`.

One workaround is to use your own little reverse proxy, which reads from `~/.m2/repository` and tell Bazel to download from `localhost`. I've created [bazel-maven-proxy](https://github.com/salesforce/bazel-maven-proxy) for this purpose. It does support proxies the same way Bazel does, i.e. reading http(s) and no_proxy environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the `maven_jar` rule. It is being deprecated in favor of the Maven resolver ruleset [`rules_jvm_external`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external).

In `rules_jvm_external`, you can use a proxy through the `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables ([documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/#proxies)), and set a custom repository URL with auth credentials ([documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/#usage)).